# How to check li element using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make checked `ul li` elements using jQuery.

Here are the `ul li` elements:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="d" data-dividertheme="c" id="layerslist" 
class="ui-listview ui-listview-inset ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-group-theme-d">

   <li data-icon="check" class=""><a class="geomind-list-item ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-check"> "valves1" </a></li>
   <li data-icon="check" class=""><a class="geomind-list-item ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-check"> "valves2" </a></li>
   <li data-icon="check" class=""><a class="geomind-list-item ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-check"> "valves3" </a></li>
   <li data-icon="check" class=""><a class="geomind-list-item ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-check"> "valves4" </a></li>

</ul>
```

I want to make a checked `li` element that has `"valves3"` text.

How do I check the `li` element that has `"valves3"` text?

Comment: How exactly does one 'check' an `<li>` element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how you want it to be checked, but try something like this.

```js
$('#layerslist li a').click(function() {
  $("#layerslist li.checked").removeClass("checked");
  $(this).parent().addClass("checked");
})
```

```css
li.checked {
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="d" data-dividertheme="c" id="layerslist" class="ui-listview ui-listview-inset ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-group-theme-d">

  <li data-icon="check" class=""><a class="geomind-list-item ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-check"> "valves1" </a></li>
  <li data-icon="check" class=""><a class="geomind-list-item ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-check"> "valves2" </a></li>
  <li data-icon="check" class=""><a class="geomind-list-item ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-check"> "valves3" </a></li>
  <li data-icon="check" class=""><a class="geomind-list-item ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-check"> "valves4" </a></li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for post.and how can I make be clicked by jquery?

Comment: @Michael, you mean is auto click it, don't need user click ?

Comment: @Michael Is this what you want?